# USB ports in Linux system

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

When I check "/sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices" in a Linux system, I could see that two devices are on the same port(T: line in below output). Also the port numbers in "D:" line is different.

Device1:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480  MxCh= 8
B:  Alloc=  0/800 us ( 0%), #Int=  2, #Iso=  0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev= 3.10
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.12 ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms
```

Device2:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480  MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=8087 ProdID=07e6 Rev= 0.17
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   1 Ivl=256ms
```

Is there something like physical USB port and logical USB port in Linux USB subsystem.
If so, then can you help in understanding physical and logical USB ports.

Comment: `D:` line has no word *port*. Read USB topology description to get this better (hint: host controller -> hub -> port -> device -> endpoint).

Comment: Device 1 has Parent 00 (root hub), while device 2 has Parent 01.  The Prnt/Port combination is unique per bus.  `lsusb -t` will show the tree view.

Comment: I was trying to understand about root hub, it seems root hub is a phony device which directly attaches to host controller. Can you please tell me, the no.of downstream ports provided by root hub will be fixed or varies based any logic.

Comment: I have a doubt about port numbers of the devices connected to the root hub. The port numbers assigned to the devices connected to root hub will be same after every reboot of the Linux system.